# my sites not creating site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, farm-setup, sharepoint-farm

Configure user profile, search , managed metadata

I only have one web application. The root site is a team site.
The mysite host site is installed at the managed path http://server/my which is a explicit managed path

I have also created another managed path for my sites. But
Created a team site at the root and a mysite at http://server/my

**The user can open the mysite but no site collection is created.**

Self Site creation is turned on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the sites using powershell and created a task schedule job to run daily.

More about the [script](http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/script-creating-sharepoint-user-mysites.html)

```
$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($MySiteRootURL);            
     try            
     {            
      $serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;            
      $upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);             
      if($upm.UserExists($Username) -eq $false)            
      {            
       Write-Host "User $Username was not found in the profile store." -f yellow;            
       return;            
      }            
      $userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile($Username);            
      if($userProfile.PersonalSite -eq $Null)            
      {            
       Write-Host "Creating MySite for user $Username" -f darkyellow;            
       $userProfile.CreatePersonalSite();                  
       Write-host "Successfully created MySite for user $Username" -f green;            
      }            
      else            
      {            
       Write-Host "User $Username already has a MySite." -f darkgreen;            
      }            
     }            
     catch            
     {            
      Write-Host "Encountered an error creating a MySite for user $Username. Error:"$_.Exception -f Red;            
     }            
     finally            
     {            
      $site.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure self-service site creation is turned on and configured for the web app hosting your mysite.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the team site on root of the web application as per the Technet:

> My Sites require that a site collection exist at the web application
>   root (which is displayed as / in the user interface). Without this,
>   you will receive a message that states that there is no site
>   collection at the root when you try to enable self-service site
>   creation for the web application. Because we recommend that you use a
>   dedicated web application to host My Sites, you should use the root
>   path for the My Site host collection unless you have a specific
>   requirement to create the site collection deeper in the uniform
>   resource locator (URL) path.

the reason why they need the MySite Host site collection on the root of the web app is decribed here:

> Although not recommended, if you create the My Site host deeper in the
>   path, it must be under an explicit inclusion managed path.
>   Additionally, you must create a separate site collection at the web
>   application root, although this site collection can be empty and
>   created without a template.
>
> The URL for a My Site host site collection
>
> > is shared by all users of the same User Profile service application.
> >     **The URL for Newsfeed is http://hostname/default.aspx**, and the URL for
> >     About Me is http://hostname/person.aspx, where hostname is the address
> >     of the site collection. For example, **if you configure your My Site
> >     host site collection at http://contoso.com/my, users access their
> >     newsfeeds and profiles at http://contoso.com/my/default.aspx and
> >     http://contoso.com/my/person.aspx, respectively.**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396